# Bash Regex Syntax For Excluding All With :space: At end of String?

Tags: regex, bash

How do I get this to test true only for all numbers or characters at end of $trig_chars var except a space?

Examples:  trig_chars='--'.  Match: --a --ab --abc --123.  But Don't match --[space] (-- followed by a space).

```
    local compare_scan_text=${scan_text:0:$trig_chars_len}

    if [[ "$compare_scan_text" =~ "$trig_chars"[^ ]* ]]; then # Trig char forward hit.

        local l=${#hotstring}
        local scan_text=${scan_text:$l} # Remove chars & hotscan_texts from scan_text.
        local hotstring=${hotsring:$trig_chars_len} # Remove trig chars.

        hotstrings+=("$hotstring") # Update hotsrings list
    fi
```

Comment: Can you give examples of values that should/shouldn't match?

Comment: Examples:  trig_chars='--'.  Match --a --b --123 -aaa.  But don't match -- (space).

Comment: Do you mean `$trig_chars(.*[^ ]$|$)` ?

Comment: Is that for parsing arguments?

Comment: I'm trying to filter a pattern match from a longer text string.  Pattern is $trig_char followed by any characters until a space is found.  I think I might have setup the solution wrong to begin with.

Comment: if `$trig_chars_len` is `2` then the `if [[ ]]` will never match.

Comment: Please use formattings in both your Q and comments - you should [have learned](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) that by now. It would make reading your examples much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example Input:

```
compare_scan_text="--a -- why -not ---me? --ab --abc --{xyz}"
```

- with GNU grep:

```sh
grep -Po '(?<=^|\s)--[^\s-]+' <<< "$compare_scan_text"
```

- with POSIX awk:

```sh
awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^--[^-]/) print $i}' <<< "$compare_scan_text"
```

outputs:

```
--a
--ab
--abc
--{xyz}
```

---

#### Replying to the comment:

Here the `grep` solution is for (almost) Linux only, while the `awk` one is for every POSIX compliant OS (which means almost all OSs); so personally I would choose `awk`.

In terms of overhead, generally speaking, when calling an external command you have to make sure to use it **outside** of the `read` loop (instead of calling it for each line inside the loop):

**DON'T DO THIS**:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

hotstrings=()

while IFS='' read -r line
do
    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a matches < <(
        awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^--[^-]/) print $i}' <<< "$line"
    )
    hotstrings+=( "${matches[@]}" )
done < file.txt
```

**DO THIS INSTEAD:**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# bash version < 4
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a hotstrings < <(
    awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^--[^-]/) print $i}' < file.txt
)

# bash version >= 4
mapfile -t hotstrings < <(
    awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^--[^-]/) print $i}' < file.txt
)

# bash version >= 4.3
readarray -d '' -t hotstrings < <(
    awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^--[^-]/) printf "%s%c", $i, 0}' < file.txt
)
```

Comment: ...When to use awk vs sed vs grep?  Grep would be lowest processing overhead and most universal right?  Awk the highest?

Comment: Updated the answer for replying to your comment

Comment: @Emily *Fixed* my updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ $compare_scan_text =~ ^"$trig_chars"(.*[^ ]$|$) ]] ; then
```

i.e. $trig_chars can be followed by anything if the last char is not a space, or it can be followed by nothing at all.

By quoting the variable, the characters are interpreted literally.